# Heroku Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) despite -Xmx being set

Tags: java, heroku, jvm

I have a Spring Boot app which slightly exceeds Heroku 512m limit, I tried setting JAVA_OPTS with appropriate value:

```
JAVA_OPTS: -Xmx384m -Xms384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

But it has absolutely zero effect. Does anyone know how can I make JVM use less than 512m?

Answer (score 0):

It might simply not be possible. When you're using Spring there is a lot of memory overhead for the framework and it's components. But you can try lowering your heap size:

```
-Xmx300m -Xms300m
```

This is more in-line with the Heroku defaults, so you can actually set nothing at all if you prefer.

Comment: sooo, what's the difference between this and what i've already tried? You mean 300 would work and 384 wouldn't?

Comment: Yes. Lower heap means less memory use. You might even go lower than 300

Comment: so when I set heap to 384, it in fact uses 384 + X, where X is unknown?

Comment: Yes. The JVM uses more memory than heap alone